# Is there a difference between awk 'NR%2==1', awk 'FNR%2', and sed 'n;d'?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I'm currently preparing for a big contest. Is there a difference between the following three commands? The exercice asks to us to print every other line of a command `ls -l`, starting from the first line.

The first command:

```
ls -l | awk 'NR%2==1'
```

The second:

```
ls -l | awk 'FNR%2'
```

The third:

```
ls -l | sed 'n;d'
```

I wrote the third one. The first two, I'm not sure I understand what they do.

Comment: A quick note re: title edits: In general, any title that uses "this" or "these" means someone would have to click through and read the question body to understand what a question is actually about. Try to avoid that whenever at all possible, in favor of putting details into the title itself.

Comment: Hi Charles, ok I will remember that, sorry ! I did'nt want to make a "clickbait". :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `awk`, `NR` and `FNR` are the record number of the current input line, starting at `1` for the first line. If you're processing multiple input files, `FNR` gets reset back to `1` at the beginning of each file, while `NR` keeps incrementing. In your case, since the input comes from `stdin` rather than named files, the two variables are equivalent.

`%` is the modulus operator, `x % y` is the remainder when dividing `x` by `y`. It's commonly used to determine if a number is odd or even by using `y = 2`; even numbers have a remainder `0`, odd numbers have remainder `1`.

```
awk '<expression>'
```

will print the current input record whenever `<expression>` is truthy. `NR % 2 == 1` is true when `NR` is odd (as explained above). `FNR % 2` is also true in the same situation, because any non-zero number is considered truthy.

So both `awk` commands print the odd-numbered lines of the `ls -l` output.

Comment: Okay thank you very much for your explanation. But I also want to know if I can use the third command to have the same result than the first two ? In other words : if I use the third command, could it be accepted as the first two ? Sorry for my bad english ! Thank you !

Comment: Yes, it has the same result.

Comment: `n` writes the current line to the output and reads the next line. `d` skips writing the current line, so that second line is skipped.